# MATLAB 2014b getframe causes UI to 'blank'

Tags: matlab, refresh, save-as

I am currently developing a complex MATLAB application. I am trying to save figures (created within its UI) by using the `getframe` function. This works fine, and saves the figure as intended. However, the UI 'blanks' after every use. The window remains but becomes a uniform white rectangle. Mousing over features in the UI makes them appear again (like a fog-of-war). Adding a `refresh` statement did not help.

Why does this happen? How do i make it stop?

Irritatingly this doesn't happen in 2018a, but the code is in 2014b, which is problematic (something I discovered after being pleased at my cool fix :( ).

Unfortunately posting code is not feasible because I do not have permission to share it.

Comment: How would you do it in 18a?

Comment: Whoops I made an error; will make an edit. i did it the same way, but this 'blanking' problem didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after much research I've been unable to find a *direct* solution. But I have implemented an indirect solution.

```
refresh
```

was not working so I implemented a manual, forced redraw. I.e. I jitter the screen after getframe by 1 pixel, which redraws the window.

```
figpos = fig.Position;    
jitter = figpos;
jitter(3) = jitter(3) + 1;
jitter(4) = jitter(4) + 1;
set(fig,'Position',jitter);
set(fig,'Position',figpos);
```

It's probably unnecessary to expand, and contract, both the width and height of the window, but it does the job fine.